# Algorithm to split data pairwise to assign to multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, partitioning, combinatorics

Suppose I've got a set of data that needs to be processed pairwise (order of pair elements does not matter, so these are combinations, not permutations), and I'd like to take advantage of multiple threads to do so.  However, I'm constrained in that each piece of data can be processed by a single thread at a time.  I'm looking for an algorithm that will provide a good partitioning strategy by which I can assign pairs of data to threads while covering the whole space of possible combinations once, for any size set of data.  Assume that processing time is equal for each possible pair.

For example, suppose I've got 6 pieces of data: D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, and D5.

To process these optimally, I would do something like this:

```
               Thread 1    Thread 2    Thread 3
Time Slot 1     (D0,D5)     (D1,D4)     (D2,D3)
Time Slot 2     (D0,D4)     (D1,D3)     (D2,D5)
Time Slot 3     (D0,D3)     (D1,D2)     (D4,D5)
Time Slot 4     (D0,D2)     (D1,D5)     (D3,D4)
Time Slot 5     (D0,D1)     (D2,D4)     (D3,D5)
```

Similarly, for 8 pieces of data: D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7

```
               Thread 1    Thread 2    Thread 3    Thread 4
Time Slot 1     (D0,D7)     (D1,D6)     (D2,D5)     (D3,D4)
Time Slot 2     (D0,D6)     (D1,D5)     (D2,D4)     (D3,D7)
Time Slot 3     (D0,D5)     (D1,D4)     (D2,D3)     (D6,D7)
Time Slot 4     (D0,D4)     (D1,D3)     (D2,D7)     (D5,D6)
Time Slot 5     (D0,D3)     (D1,D2)     (D4,D6)     (D5,D7)
Time Slot 6     (D0,D2)     (D1,D7)     (D3,D6)     (D4,D5)
Time Slot 7     (D0,D1)     (D2,D6)     (D3,D5)     (D4,D7)
```

I figured out the above on my own by hand, but the process I had to use was slightly different for each and thus seems hard to translate into code to generate these for larger sets of data.  Any ideas for an algorithm to generate these pairs properly and efficiently?  Tried to search for a solution but not sure exactly how to phrase the problem better to get the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas for an algorithm to generate these pairs properly and efficiently?

A simple solution would be to create a boolean in-use array corresponding to each of your data pieces.  As the data is being worked on it goes to true and then when the work is finished on them it returns to false.  You also create a to-be-done queue all of the combinations of your data pieces: [d0, d1], [d0, d2], [d0, d3], ....

Have a single scheduler thread that goes through the to-be-done queue and finds data pairs where both data pieces are currently not in-use.   It checks the in-use array for both data pieces, sets the in-use array to true for both data items, and puts the pair in the work-queue to be processed by the threads.  When it finds a pair where one (or both) are in-use, it adds it to the end of the to-be-done queue.  As the results are returned, it sets the in-use status back to false.  Repeat until the to-be-done queue is empty and all in-use is false.

This single scheduler thread spins a bit as it finds collisions but the number of spins should be a relatively small percentage of CPU compared to the processing.

So it would do:

- Check [d0, d1].  Neither in use.  d0 is now in-use.  d1 is now in-use.  Schedule.
- Check [d0, d2].  d0 is in use.
- Check [d0, d3].  d0 is in use.
  ...
- Check [d1, d2].  d1 is in use.
  ...
- Check [d2, d3].  Neither in use.  d2 is now in-use.  d3 is now in-use.  Schedule.
  ...

Initially there will be a lot of spinning but the check against the boolean array is a trivial amount of work.  One thing to improve it is to once and a while shuffle the to-be-done queue.

Comment: That helps.  The code I was given and am trying to improve upon did something similar to this, but it used a true "queue" of to-be-done items (that was ordered poorly) and would block until it could assign the next item in the queue to a thread.  So originally I was going down the road of trying to come up with the best way to divvy up the work ahead of time where this approach just finds the next thing available that can be processed.  Not sure its optimal, but probably good enough for my purposes.  Thanks for providing this perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

- Create a job queue having all combinations
- Create a status array indicating status of the tasks (true is running, false is not running)
- Initialize tasksToBeProcessed to the no of jobs in the queue

Have a worker thread, that has run having following logic

```
while(tasksToBeProcessed > 0) {  
    Remove next job from the job queue
    //check the status array
    if (Both the tasks are not running)
        Change the status array and mark tasks as running
    else
        Put the job back in the queue
    continue;

    //process the tasks
    Decrement tasksToBeProcessed by 1
}
```

Here, worker threads keep processing the jobs till there is no job left to be processed. This does not required any thread spinning. Only important thing is to check care of thread safety while accessing status array and queue

Comment: How is this different from my answer 13 hours previous?

Comment: @Gray Basically you are suggesting a scheduler thread to check to-be done queue.  What I am suggesting is that all worker thread will pick up the jobs to be processed on their own one-after another from the queue So there is no need of scheduler thread..the way typical thread-pool worker threads work..